# Can't use Ember.Logger.info("text here"); inside an authenticator

Tags: debugging, logging, ember.js

I'm trying to figure out why my authenticated token info back from 3rd party service isn't saved in my session. Parts of the code in the authenticator file are working as expected but not saving to session.

I would like to verify what the session is by using a debug statement but nothing comes to the browser because of redirects. Is there a way to make the Ember.Logger print out to file? or the cli?

Ember.Logger.info("text here");

Comment: Ember.Logger.*whatever* is kind of a wrapper to console.*whatever*. So I'm not sure how you'd log it to a file when your app is running on the browser. You could override it so it sends the response to some service that saves a file to file system. But you can always set a break point and debug

Comment: What do you mean you "can't use Logger.info"? Are you sure you didn't filter info messages in the console?

Comment: This isn't an ember error. Ember is working, my code wasn't.

Comment: There is a fancy checkbox *Preserve log upon navigation* in the chrome dev tools settings. This keep the log alive on redirects.